# how the computer switch operation from one thread to another

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am a newbie to the multithread programming. After some research about the functions, e.g. join, sleep, joinable, I am still confused how does the computer decide when to switch operation from one thread into another thread? Let's say that you have one core with multiple threads, have an infinite while loop in each thread (e.g. while(true)), and forget about the mutex locks for now. If the while loop is always on, how does the computer switch?

Is this where the sleep_for function comes in?

Comment: Operating systems run schedulers to decide, which threads a runnable at a specific point of time.

Comment: You can see that for kernel of some particular operating system. For example, you can start from http://www.quora.com/How-does-thread-switching-differ-from-process-switching.

Comment: @user1929959 The link is not directly related to my question but is very helpful for understanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the operating system starts running a thread, it arranges for the hardware to interrupt it when the thread's time slice is over. If nothing else happens and the thread does get to use up its full timeslice, this interrupt will trigger the operating system to switch threads.

Comment: The default Linux timeslice is defined in the Linux kernel as RR_TIMESLICE in include/linux/sched/rt.h

Comment: I see. In that case, (1) sleep_for function has nothing to do with the switch, (2) lock(mutex) will be used to prevent that switch-over even after that timeslice.

Comment: @villybyun If you call `sleep_for`, the scheduler will switch to a different thread and might arrange to switch back to you at the requested time if it can. Locking a mutex doesn't prevent a switch over.

Comment: Got it. This helps me understand other references as well. Thanks.

Comment: Also priority is a factor, the operating system will do an immediate context switch to a higher priority thread when it's state changes from pending to runnable.

Comment: @rcgldr: That assumes (A) a lack of CPU cores and (B) an actual interrupt making the thread runnable (This may be a timer interrupt, especially if the high-priority thread was in a timed sleep). Without an interrupt, the CPU will be executing user-mode code instead of the OS.

Comment: @MSalters - I should have mentioned the single core situation, since that is what I assumed the original question was about, switching from one thread to another. Threads on different cores can run in parallel. Getting back to the multiple threads on a single core case, any thread currently running could set an event, mutex, semaphore, ... , that the the higher priority thread was pending on, resulting in an immediate context switch to the higher priority thread (no interrupt needed).

Comment: @MSalters -  Continuing, if all threads are pending, then at least one of those threads is pending on some interrupt, and the processor could go into a lower power states. For X86, a halt instruction is often used while in an idle mode (I don't know if this is a low power state).